# KnockoutJS custom component loader not executing `loadViewModel`

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-components

**Context**

I have been fiddling around and trying to create my own (just another) SPA framework. In this framework I've been trying to create a custom component loader to be able to do some dependency injection 'n stuff on the viewModels I'm loading.

*Used KnockoutJS version: 3.3.0*

**Problem**

The `loadViewModel` function on the custom component loader isn't executing when a component is loaded.

Code for reference ([see file](http://gitvc.net/CorstianBoerman/spa-template/blob/master/src/app/core/componentLoader.js)):

```
injector(function (ko) {
    ko.components.loaders.unshift({
        getConfig: function (name, callback) {
            var parts = name.split("/");
            callback({
                require: "components/" + name + "/" + parts[parts.length - 1]
            });
        },
        loadViewModel: function (name, viewModelConfig, callback) {
            console.log(arguments);
            callback(null);
        }
    });
});
```

Please not that the `injector` function is just some custom dependency resolver I wrote. (Almost like a `define` or `require` call on AMD components.)

The `getConfig` function gets executed properly whatsoever.

For a complete overview of my doodling, [see this git repo](http://gitvc.net/CorstianBoerman/spa-template/tree/master)

Comment: In your `viewModel.js` the `viewModel: func.apply(this.models[identifier], arguments)` does not correclty set the viewModel property which remains `undefined` because of that the `loadComponent` method of the he default component does not call your `loadViewModel` method. So you need to return a proper viewModel object/function from your  `viewModel.js`

Comment: @nemesv Please submit it as answer so I can accept it as I believe this is the root cause. Anyway, any thoughts on how to make the viewModel actually return it's viewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't "override" the `loadComponent` method then the default component loader's `loadComponent` will be invoked which only calls the `loadViewModel` if you've provided a `viewModel` config option.

In your `getConfig` method you are returning a config with `require` which means that your require.js module has to provide the necessary `viewModel` config option.

However in your `viewModel.js` the

```
viewModel: func.apply(this.models[identifier], arguments)
```

does not correclty set the `viewModel` property which remained `undefined`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to seek through my code. The last sentence in your answer is probably the best pointer for people struggling with the same problem :)